# Recursive templates: inheritance vs composition

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

My C++ skills are a little bit rusty, dating back to C++99, so I decided to take some time to practice more evolved metaprogramming.

I'm trying to use recursive templates to implement a Vector class.
I find two way of doing:

1. Using inheritance: In that case, a vector of dimension N inherits from a vector of dimension N-1. See #1 sample code below.
2. Using composition: In that case, a vector of dimension N is made of a value and a vector of dimension N-1. See #2 sample code below.

As far as metaprogramming in C++ is concerned, is there any advantage in doing one way or the other? Are there some pitfalls to expects if I follow one path or the other? Or would the compiler be able to do mostly the same job in both cases?

```
//
// Sample code 1 -- Using inheritance
//
template<unsigned int DIM>
class VectorND : VectorND<DIM-1> {
    private:
    double _n;

    public:
    template<class N, class... Rest>
    VectorND(N n, Rest... rest): _n(n), VectorND<DIM-1>(rest...) {};
};

template<>
class VectorND<0> {

};

int main() {
    VectorND<3> v(1,2,3);

}
```

---

```
//
// Sample code 2 -- Using composition
//
template<unsigned int DIM>
class VectorND {
    private:
    VectorND<DIM-1> _base;
    double _n;

    public:
    template<class N, class... Rest>
    VectorND(N n, Rest... rest): _n(n), _base(rest...) {};
};

template<>
class VectorND<0> {

};

int main() {
    VectorND<3> v(1,2,3);

}
```

Comment: Dependent name is generally more surprising with inheritance.

Comment: Btw, `std::array<double, N>` does the job (with member similar to `double data[N];`).

Comment: @Jarod42 I feel like this would be simpler as well (and possibly faster to compile because less instantiations?)

Comment: FWIW, with inheritance, the code seems more verbose than when using composition. About `std::array<double, N>` -- indeed, but this is mostly a pretext for me to practice with "modern" templates ;)

Comment: @Borgleader: For Meta prog, "complexity" is indeed in number of instantiation.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: `VectorND` seems mostly useless for meta programming (runtime access in `O(n)`, ...). MultiDimensionalArray (Matrix) seems more interesting (either `vector<vector<vector<..>>>` or flat `vector` with index transformation).

Comment: @Jarod42 _"runtime access in O(n)"_

To be honest, after having read a couple of articles on the topic, I was hoping the compiler to be able to optimize at compile time simple arithmetics operations (`operator +=`) so runtime complexity would be `O(1)`. Your last comment is quite disappointing :/

Comment: How do you implement `v[2]` ? You cannot do `static_cast<double*>(this) + n` or similar, you have to go with something like `return (index == DIM - 1) ? _n : _base[index];` (or create an (temporary) array). But indeed a `v.at<2>()` would be `O(1)`.

Comment: Btw `v._n` is `1`, and `v._base._base._n` or `v.VectorND<1>::_n` is `3`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I was implementing operator[] exactly how you suggested when you replied. _Apparently_ by looking at the object dump, when compiling with `g++ -O2` the code is optimized so the recursive calls are eliminated--resulting in an O(1) complexitiy at runtime. Or did I missed something?

Comment: Good that compiler optimize that, but it is not required. (and small variation might not be optimized).

Comment: Indeed @Jarod42. Thank you for your time.